# Adding flip animation while navigating through page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I have applied a flip animation while navigating to chat page but the problem is that my page is getting flipped first and then text rendered on that page is flipping.So what can I do to flip both text and page simultaneously?

HTML

```
<div ui-sref="chat"  class="title">
    <a href="#/app/chat">
      <img class = "title-image" src="img/Chat@1x.png"></img>
          <p class="imgtext" style="color: rgb(102, 0, 0)">Chat</p>
    </a><br>
    </div>'
```

CHAT.HTML

```
 <ion-view view-title="Chat" id="animation">
 <ion-header-bar >
 <a onclick="history.back()" > Back </a>
 <h1 class="title">Chat</h1> 
 </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  <div > 
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>`
```

CSS

```
   @keyframes example {

    to      { transform: rotateY(180deg);animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
}
#animation{
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
 perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With you CSS you are going to run the Animation bevore the new page is even loaded. You have to trigger the Animation with Angular/Ionic on the actual change of the Page.

Maybe this Article helps:

http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-animate-your-ionic-app-with-animate-css-and-nganimate/

**ngAnimate** is the Thing you are looking for.

Comment: I have already tried ng-Animate :) and in that page is getting rotate but no the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FLIP as a transition animation then the best solution would be to use this plugin which handles it very smoothly.

https://github.com/shprink/ionic-native-transitions

You can either put the same flip transition for all pages or you can control it for a particular page

Eg.

```
$ionicNativeTransitions.stateGo('yourState', {}, {}, {
    "type": "flip",
    "direction": "right", // 'left|right|up|down', default 'left' (which is like 'next')
    "duration": 1500, // in milliseconds (ms), default 400
});
```

Comment: I have done the same way they have mentioned and still getting error

Comment: I am getting this - "Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ionic-native-transitions' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."